# Union operation in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to quickly perform union operations in edit mode.  Not using modifiers.  [The manual for 2.93](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/intersect_boolean.html) refers to Intersect/Union/Difference capabilities within the Face -> Intersect (Boolean) menu, but but I don't see any way to configure the operation to use union.  How do I change the operation to union from intersect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>F9</kbd> after invoking the operation, or expand menu at bottom left corner:

[image]